# Extracting data between HTML tags using regular expression

Tags: php, html, regex

Extracting data between HTML tags using regular expression

I have this example which successfully, takes the value from name and put in into three different arrays

```
$str = '&lt;ul&gt;
&lt;li&gt;&lt;a name="valuehere1" title="titlehere" href="/channel/london/"&gt;Link1&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;&lt;a name="valuehere2" title="titlehere" href="/channel/games/"&gt;Link1&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;&lt;a name="valuehere3" title="titlehere" href="/channel/sport/"&gt;Link1&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;/ul&gt;';

preg_match_all('/&lt;li&gt;&lt;a name="(.*)" title/', $str, $m);
print_r($m);
```

---

I am not hot having any luck with the code below. I am trying to extract all the data between `&lt;ul class="statelist"&gt;(.*) &lt;/ul&gt;` tags, but it is just returning two empty arrays

```
$data = '&lt;ul class="statelist"&gt;
                &lt;li&gt;&lt;a href="http://www.mymovingreviews.com/usa/alabama-movers-al-1"&gt;Alabama (45)&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;
                &lt;li&gt;&lt;a href="http://www.mymovingreviews.com/usa/alaska-movers-ak-2"&gt;Alaska (4)&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;
                &lt;li&gt;&lt;a href="http://www.mymovingreviews.com/usa/arizona-movers-az-3"&gt;Arizona (113)&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;                     
                &lt;/ul&gt;';

preg_match_all('/&lt;ul class="statelist"&gt;(.*) &lt;\/ul&gt;/', $data, $m);

print_r($m);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add s option to your regex

```
preg_match_all('/&lt;ul class="statelist"&gt;(.*) &lt;\/ul&gt;/s', $data, $m);
                                                              ^^^^ here
```

It will make your regex accept word wraps (\n character). ([See the doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs.aspx))